# angular 2 use method for properties

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to call the method setItemSrc and use item as parameter. How do I do that?

```
<img *ng-for="#item of items"
                    [src]="setSrc(item)"
                    [style.left]="item.x"
                    [style.top]="item.y"
                    (click)="clickedItem(item)">
                 </img>

 public setItemSrc(item:Item):string{
       var str:string="/img/item"
       str=str.concat(item.categorie);
       return str;
}
```

Comment: You're doing it right, `setSrc(item)` in the template needs to be `seItemSrc(item)` to match the name of the method though, obviously...

Answer (score 2):

> I want to call the method setItemSrc and use item as parameter

`[src]="setSrc(item)"` should be `[src]="setItemSrc(item)"`

Comment: i had an other problem. It is solved. Thanks for the answers